# Do Klingons Respect Human Warriors from Antiquity?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, federation

In general, especially before the Treaty of Alliance, and the earlier neutral zone cease-fires, the Klingons thought very lowly of humanity.

However, fast-forward, in time to after the Treaty of Alliance, the Klingons likely would have access to human history. Would they have gained further respect for humanity after learning that WE had warriors much like theirs for many centuries (before we evolved to our technological advancement in the Federation), like Roman soldiers, Greek Spartans, or Samurais?

Yes the Federation has "warriors" of sorts, in combat-trained field officers for away missions and tactical officers and security officers on starships, but I'm referring to the Klingons' native passion for up-close and personal hand to hand combat with sharp blades and death. Humanity has essentially evolved beyond that by the time of the Federation.

So if a Klingon read about Sparta, Rome, or Imperial Japan, would that change their perspective on humanity quite a bit? Are there any episodes/scenes in any of the series/films/books where a Klingon mentions human warriors of old? I'm not asking for opinion-based answers. I'm asking for answers based upon 1) factual mentions in any Star Trek series/films/books, and 2) factual data based upon the Star Trek universe (memory alpha, any other resources).

Comment: Nope. The Klingons respect only actions

Comment: Voted to leave open, if only for _"Are there any episodes/scenes in any of the series/films where a Klingon mentions human warriors of old?"_. That doesn't seem POB, and if Klingons only respect actions, well that's an answer

Comment: They ought to respect humans in general.  Every time a "warrior" Klingon encounters a human, the Klingon gets his own ass handed to him on a silver platter.

Comment: @JRE Not quite true, especially in DS9 during the Federation-Klingon war.

Comment: I mainly ask because Klingons do have an element of "I hate your guts, but you are clearly a worthy opponent who will make our battle hard-fought, which will be more gloroius". So my thought process behind this question is: do Klingons dream of what it would have been like if they had gone up against a Spartan, or a Samauri, instead of a neatly-dressed Starfleet officer, and thus are there any references to human historical "warriors" in their dialogue on any of the series/films?

Comment: The problem here is that the title question doesn't seem to match what you're actually asking in the last paragraph and the title question is pretty much POB. And then because of this distinction some other sentences could mean 1 of 2 things and so that also makes this fall into unclear and too broad territory. Fixing the title to be more specific would help clean this up but you may need to clarify some of the sentences in the post itself as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It's quite clear from the body of the question what OP is driving at. I've edited the title to reflect

Comment: They respect Shakespeare, a warrior of words.

Comment: Yes, but Chang seems to believe shakespeare was klingon, as he says its better in its original klingon text

Comment: I interpreted that as Chang had a sense of humor.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that Klingons do respect human warriors as individuals, even if they do not have a high opinion of humanity as a whole.  This was true even before the *Next Generation* era.  Consider, for example, this ominous dialogue from *[Star Trek VI](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie6.html)*:

[image: Chang, Kerla, and Kirk]

> GENERAL CHANG:  I've always wanted to meet you, Captain.
>   KIRK:  I'm not sure how to take that.
>   BRIGADIER KERLA:  Sincere admiration, Kirk, ....
>   CHANG:  ... from one warrior to another.

It is not entirely clear whether Chang is actually sincere in his admiration, but Kerla certainly seems to be.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked *"So if a Klingon read about Sparta, Rome, or Imperial Japan, would that change their perspective on humanity quite a bit? Are there any episodes/scenes in any of the series/films where a Klingon mentions **human warriors of old?"***